# manipulating array of json data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a project where I have to take some data from a GoogleSheet document and send it to database.
I get the data from googlesheet document, but the problem is how is the data structured.

```json
[
  {
    class: "A",
    name: "Alex",
    age: 13
  },
  {
    class: "A",
    name: "Mary",
    age: 14
  },
  {
    class: "B",
    name: "John",
    age: 13
  },
  {
    class: "B",
    name: "William",
    age: 12
  }
]
```

The problem is I want my JSON object to look like this

```json
[
  "A": {
    {
      name: "Alex",
      age: 13
    },
    {
      name: "Mary",
      age: 13
    }
  },
  "B": {
    {
      name: "John",
      age: 13
    },
    {
      name: "William",
      age: 13
    }
  }
]
```

Any idea how can I do that? I want to group my objects over an element, like the class. All the people with the same class value to be in the same group/json.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the `Array.prototype.reduce` function?

Comment: The output you are looking for is not a valid json. It should be array of objects something like `{"A":[{"name":"Alex","age":13},{"name":"Mary","age":14}]}`

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and format it.

```js
let data = [{class:"A",name:"Alex",age:13},{class:"A",name:"Mary",age:14},{class:"B",name:"John",age:13},{class:"B",name:"William",age:12}];

//destructuring and renaming it to `_` as `class` is a pre-defined identifier in javascript
const formatData = (data) => data.reduce((res, {
  class: _,
  ...rest
}) => {
//(res[_] || []) --> If the `class` prop is not already present in the res object, then using empty array
//If already present spreading res[_] and adding the current object to the existing array
  res[_] = [...(res[_] || []), { ...rest }]
  return res;
}, {})

console.log(formatData(data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

You can have a look at [`Destructuring Assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for more info about destructuring and assigning new variable names.